# The truth value of array is ambigous

Tags: arrays, valueerror, sudoku

I have gotten this error a few times in my code and I've never come across it before. Sudoku is a 2d numpy array. Can anyone tell me why and how to fix it?

An example of the sudoku array would be

```
sudoku = np.array([[0, 2, 4, 7, 6, 3, 5, 9, 1], [3, 9, 7, 4, 5, 0, 8, 2, 6], [8, 5, 6, 9, 2, 0, 0, 4, 7], [0, 8, 9, 5, 3, 6, 7, 1, 4], [7, 3, 1, 2, 9, 4, 6, 5, 8], [6, 4, 5, 8, 1, 7, 9, 3, 2], [4, 7, 2, 3, 8, 9, 1, 6, 5], [9, 1, 8, 6, 4, 5, 2, 7, 3], [5, 6, 3, 1, 7, 2, 4, 8, 9]])
```

```
import numpy as np
import copy
global subgrids
sudoku = np.array([[0, 2, 4, 7, 6, 3, 5, 9, 1], [3, 9, 7, 4, 5, 0, 8, 2, 6], [8, 5, 6, 9, 2, 0, 0, 4, 7], [0, 8, 9, 5, 3, 6, 7, 1, 4], [7, 3, 1, 2, 9, 4, 6, 5, 8], [6, 4, 5, 8, 1, 7, 9, 3, 2], [4, 7, 2, 3, 8, 9, 1, 6, 5], [9, 1, 8, 6, 4, 5, 2, 7, 3], [5, 6, 3, 1, 7, 2, 4, 8, 9]])
ad = sudoku.tolist()
frontier = sudoku

subgrids = []
moves = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

columns = []
for i in range(0,9):
  columns.append([row[i] for row in sudoku])  

def is_possible(sudoku):
  for i in range(0, 9):
    for j in range(1, 10):
      if np.any([ad[i].count(j) > 1] or [columns[i].count(j) > 1]):
        return False
  return True



sc = copy.deepcopy(ad)
for i in range(0,9,3):
  for j in range(0,9,3):
    subgrids.append(sc[i][j:j+3]+sc[i+1][j:j+3]+sc[i+2][j:j+3])



def get_next_zero(sudoku):
  for i in range(0,9):
    for j in range(0,9):
      if sudoku[i][j] == 0:
        index = [i,j] #i is row index, j is column index
        possible_values(index,subgrids) 
  return True       

def is_solution(sudoku):
  if is_possible(sudoku) == False:
    return False
  for i in range(0,9):
    for j in range(0,9):
      if sudoku[i][j] == 0:
        return False
  return True



  




def possible_values(ind,grid):
  possible_num = []
  row = [a for a in sudoku[ind[0]]]
  row = list(row)
  column = []
  for i in range(0,9):
    column.append(sudoku[i][ind[1]])
  column = list(column)
  if ind[0] < 3:
    if ind[1] < 3:
      sub = grid[0]
    elif 2 < ind[1] < 6:
      sub = grid[1]
    else:
      sub = grid[2]
  if 2 < ind[0] < 6:
    if ind[1] < 3:
      sub = grid[3]
    elif 2 < ind[1] < 6:
      sub = grid[4]
    else:
      sub = grid[5]  
  if ind[0] > 5:
    if ind[1] < 3:
      sub = grid[6]
    elif 2 < ind[1] < 6:
      sub = grid[7]
    else:
      sub = grid[8] 
  sub = list(sub)  
  for num in moves:
    if num not in row and num not in column and num not in sub:
      possible_num.append(num)
  solver(possible_num, ind)

def solver(actions, where):
  if len(actions) < 1:
    np.delete(frontier,len(frontier)-1)
  else:
    for action in actions:
      sudoku[where[0]][where[1]] = action
      new_state = sudoku
      if is_possible(new_state) == True:
        np.append(frontier,new_state)
      else:
        np.delete(frontier,sudoku)
        new_state = frontier.pop()
    sudoku_solver(new_state)
   


def sudoku_solver(sudoku):
  if is_possible(sudoku) == False:
    print (np.full((9,9),-1))
  elif is_solution(sudoku) == True:
    print(sudoku)
  else:
    get_next_zero(sudoku)

  

sudoku_solver(sudoku)
```

```
for num in moves:
    if num not in row and num not in column and num not in sub:
      possible_num.append(num)
  solver(possible_num, ind)  

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Another point in the code too

```
def is_solution(sudoku):
  if is_possible(sudoku) == False:
    return False
  for i in range(0,9):
    for j in range(0,9):
      if sudoku[i][j] == 0:
        return False
  return True

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: The code you have shown us is not a [mre]. What does `sudoku` look like? Where does this `columns` variable come from?

Comment: The error you got is returned by numpy when you try to get a single boolean value out of an array. For example, `if np.array([False, False, True]):` will provoke that error.

Comment: Presumably, you thought that `sudoku[i].count(j)` was a number, but actually it's an array. Or you thought that `columns[i].count(j)` was a number, but actually it's an array.

Comment: Anyway there is an error somewhere in your code, and we can't find it for you. You'll have to debug your code. Either use a debugging software, or add lots of `print()` statements to check that the values of the variables are really what you think they are.

Comment: Oh ok I understand why I'm getting an error with count. But why am I getting an error in is_solution function, specifically at the line sudoku[i][j] == 0?

Comment: Presumably, you thought that `sudoku[i][j]` was a single number, but actually it's an array? Like I said, I can't debug your code for you (especially since you didn't provide it)

Comment: For instance: `sudoku = np.array([[[1,1,1], [1,1,1], [1,1,1]], [[1,1,1], [1,1,1], [1,1,1]], ]); i,j=1,1; if sudoku[i][j] == 0: print('hello')` will reproduce the error.